# Template Literals with JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript

I am wondering as to why this template literal does not work when I apply it using JavaScript DOM for css style? Your help in understanding this is greatly appreciated!

```js
let rainColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
            if (rainbows == true) {
              row.style.backgroundColor = '${rainColors[getRandomInt(6)]}';
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you're using single quotes. you need to use backquotes, like this:

```js
let rainColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
            if (rainbows == true) {
              row.style.backgroundColor = `${rainColors[getRandomInt(6)]}`;
```

By the way, there is no reason to do this:

```
`${variable}`
```

As you can just use

```
variable
```